# JQuery parse XML image tag

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I have an XML file that uses image tags like this:

```
<Entry>
    <?image_0 href="http://url.com"?>
    <?image_1 href="http://url.com"?>
    <?image_2 href="http://url.com"?>
</Entry>
```

It doesn't work using .find("?image_0") or similar since this has no closing tag. This format is supported by Adobe InDesign, but how do I get the image child elements and the URL?

Comment: You're telling me that this is the markup produced in the browser window?

Comment: It is produced to a file from InDesign and for some reason that program uses this markup for images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it valid xml by rewriting the content:

```
var data = '<Entry> <?image_0 href="http://url.com"?> <?image_1 href="http://url.com"?> <?image_2 href="http://url.com"?> </Entry>';
data = data.replace(/\<\?/g, "<").replace(/\?\>/g, "/>");
alert($(data).find("image_0").attr("href"));
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geqQ4/1/).

Comment: That will work, but I noticed that .replace only replaces symbols in the first line in the XML string instead of every instance it finds. Do you know why? I tried using text and html as dataTypes (xml creates an object I can't use replace on).

Comment: Ah, true. It is only a matter of replacing the search pattern with regex to get global searching. (i.e. `/g` above)